# Rename tag [julia-lang] to [julia]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Why is the tag for Julia (in case you're not familiar, see: [website](http://julialang.org/) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%28programming_language%29)) set as [julia-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-lang) rather than just [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia)?

It seems the only tags that involve a `-lang` construction are those that might be confused with something else:

- [slim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim-lang) (vs. [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim))
- [q-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q-lang) (vs. [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q))
- [apache-commons-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-lang) (vs. [apache-commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons))
- [factor-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor-lang) (vs. [factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factor))
- [nls-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nls-lang) (vs. [nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nls))
- [snap-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-lang) (vs. [snap-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snap-framework)).

That doesn't seem appropriate here because there is no current [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia) tag and I don't think it's likely to be confused with anything else on the site (except maybe [julia sets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=julia+-%5Bjulia-lang%5D), which don't currently have their own tag).

Can we rename [julia-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-lang) to just [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia)?

Comment: The language's home site is julialang.org, no doubt the inspiration for the tag as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make tags `julia-lang` and `julialang` synonyms of tag `julia`.

Answer (score 7):

I just want to say that I agree with op. One reason to make `julia` the default is that it would be more in line with other stack exchange sites like code review.

Comment: Code review, and also cross-validated.
AFAIK there other than the Stack-overflow they are the only other sites that have the tag, both of which use `julia`.  Cross-validated has `julia-lang` as a synonym though.

Answer (score -6):

Why?

It currently has a descriptive, unique, non-confusing name.  Why change it?